# A way to modify the redux store from a component that is not inside the Provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a component named `Listener`, it's purpose is to just listen to all the native events such as when `AppState`, `BackPress`, `NetInfo` and `Geolocation`.

I have setup my root like below:

```
class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Listener>
        <Provider>{children}</Provider>
      </Listener>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem here is I can not use `connect` from `react-redux`. Is there another way to dispatch an action or modify the store from outside the Provider scope such as `Listener` on my setup?

Basically `Provider` is not a normal `Provider` from redux, it's my custom `Provider` that I used to contain all logic in creating the redux setup in one place.

A snippet of it would be

```
export default class Provider extends Component {
   store: Object;
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.store = createStore(....);
   }
}
```

Comment: What did you want to do in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible. If you have access to the store object you created and passed to the provider, you can directly dispatch an action.
ex

```
import store from './store'

store.dispatch(increment());
```

The documentation is here,
https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store

Comment: This didn't work for me. Sorry I forgot to mention that I abstracted all my redux and persistence data inside the ProviderComponent.

Comment: @JojoNarte then make a ref to the provider inside the root component

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, even though I really wanted to have the `Listener` to be on the outer scope, I switched its place with the `Provider`

```
class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <Provider>
          <Listener>{children}</Listener>
        </Provider>

    );
  }
}
```

With this I can now use `connect` from `react-redux`. It seems to be the only cleaner way for now.